# I want to extract only a specific value using jsonpath

Tags: json-path-expression

How to use jsonpath to extract only id value from Json like below?

```js
[
      {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Code": "00",
      "options": [      {
         "id": "SS111",
         "roundTrip": false,
         "price": 53900,
         "trains": [         {
            "packageDiscount": 3244,
            "goodsType": "REGULAR"
         }],
         "adults": 1
      }],
      "type": "DOMESTIC_TRAIN"
   },
   {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Code": "00",
      "options": [      {
         "id": "SS222",
         "roundTrip": false,
         "price": 53900,
         "trains": [         {
            "packageDiscount": 3244,
            "goodsType": "REGULAR"
         }],
         "adults": 1
      }],
      "type": "DOMESTIC_TRAIN"
   }
]
```

The result I want is as below.

```
SS111,
SS222
```

Please tell me about Jsonpath.Please tell me about Jsonpath.Please tell me about Jsonpath.Please tell me about Jsonpath.Please tell me about Jsonpath.

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: once again kindly go through the documentation completely to learn and understand how Jayway jsonpath works. https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `..` - [Deep Scan operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)

```
$..id
```

Online Test Tool : https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/